# Convert string to CrmDateTime

Tags: c#, string, datetime

```
public CrmDateTime CRMFormattedDate(string dateValue)
{
    DateTime cd = new DateTime();
    string date_str = "";

    try
    {
        if (!isValidYear(dateValue.Substring(6, 4)))
            date_str = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        else
            date_str = dateValue.Substring(6, 4);

        cd.Value = date_str + "/" + dateValue.Substring(3, 2) + "/" + dateValue.Substring(0, 2) + "T00:00:00";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        cd = null; 
    }

    return cd;
}
```

The code above throws an error. I have tried to solve this problem but without any luck. Can someone assist me please?

Comment: Which error. And where?

Comment: Errors tend to have helpful information for diagnosing the problem.  Can you share that information?  Including any exception information that you're *explicitly ignoring* in your `catch` block?  (Hint: Ignoring exceptions like that is very bad practice.  Any time you find yourself wondering why something isn't working, and you're *ignoring* errors, well, that's why it isn't working.)

Comment: Please add the error you are seeing: is it a compile issue?  A crash?  Are you getting unexpected results?  Are there any error messages?  This type of info is hugely helpful when looking through questions.

Comment: You could easily put the text of the error message, exception stack, line number, etc, into your question.  This would help diagnose your issue without having to actually take your code and put it into a test project and execute it ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public CrmDateTime CRMFormattedDate(string dateValue)
{
    CrmDateTime cd = new CrmDateTime();
    string date_str = "";

    try
    {
        if (!isValidYear(dateValue.Substring(6, 4)))
            date_str = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        else
            date_str = dateValue.Substring(6, 4);

        cd.Value = date_str + "/" + dateValue.Substring(3, 2) + "/" + dateValue.Substring(0, 2) + "T00:00:00";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        cd = null; 
    }

    return cd;
}

private bool isValidYear(string year_value)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt16(year_value) < 1800)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Please try this.

Comment: I am try this code but it show error just now

Comment: @System you need to tell us what the error says.

Comment: Thanks @Sumon Banerjee. Solve my problem

Comment: @System if Sumon's answer solved your problem.  Please mark it as the answer by clicking the Green Checkmark button below the up/down arrows.

Comment: This is too long.. Find my ans.

Comment: var date = DateTime.Now;
                CrmDateTime crmdate_time = new CrmDateTime(datetime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy/MM/dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"));

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this methods helps you, all of extracted from Microsoft.Crm.Platform.Sdk.dll file.

```
public static CrmDateTime FromString(string serializedForm, string formattedDate, string formattedTime)
{
    CrmDateTime crmDateTime = new CrmDateTime();
    crmDateTime.Deserialize(serializedForm, formattedDate, formattedTime);
    return crmDateTime;
}

public override string ToString()
{
    switch (this._style)
    {
        case CrmDateTime.Style.None:
        {
            return "Uninitialized";
        }
        case CrmDateTime.Style.User:
        {
            CultureInfo invariantCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            object[] objArray = new object[] { this._userTime };
            return string.Format(invariantCulture, "(user:{0:s})", objArray);
        }
        case CrmDateTime.Style.Universal:
        {
            CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            object[] objArray1 = new object[] { this._universalTime };
            return string.Format(cultureInfo, "(universal:{0:s})", objArray1);
        }
        case CrmDateTime.Style.Both:
        {
            CultureInfo invariantCulture1 = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            object[] objArray2 = new object[] { this._userTime, this._universalTime };
            return string.Format(invariantCulture1, "(user:{0:s}, universal:{1:s})", objArray2);
        }
    }
    CultureInfo cultureInfo1 = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    object[] str = new object[] { this._style.ToString() };
    throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(cultureInfo1, "Invalid CrmDateTime style: {0}", str));
}

private void Deserialize(string serializedForm, string formattedDate, string formattedTime)
{
    DateTime dateTime;
    string str = serializedForm.Trim();
    this._formattedDate = formattedDate;
    this._formattedTime = formattedTime;
    int length = str.Length;
    if (length == 0)
    {
        throw new CrmArgumentNullException("Empty string is not a valid representation of CrmDateTime.");
    }
    if (!DateTime.TryParse(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out dateTime))
    {
        CultureInfo invariantCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        object[] objArray = new object[] { str };
        throw new CrmException(string.Format(invariantCulture, "The date-time format for {0} is invalid, or value is outside the supported range.", objArray), -2147220935);
    }
    if (str[length - 1] == 'Z' || str[length - 1] == 'z')
    {
        this.Initialize(CrmDateTime.Style.Universal, dateTime);
        return;
    }
    if (length > 6 && (str[length - 6] == '+' || str[length - 6] == '-') && str[length - 3] == ':' && str.IndexOf(':', 0, length - 6) >= 0)
    {
        string str1 = str.Substring(0, length - 6);
        DateTime dateTime1 = DateTime.Parse(str1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
        this.Initialize(dateTime1, dateTime);
        return;
    }
    DateTime dateTime2 = dateTime;
    if (!SerializationState.IsInPlatformContext)
    {
        this.Initialize(CrmDateTime.Style.User, dateTime2);
        return;
    }
    DateTime utcTime = SerializationState.ConvertUserTimeToUtcTime(dateTime2);
    this.Initialize(dateTime2, CrmDateTime.AdjustToLimits(utcTime));
}


public string Serialize()
{
    string str;
    CrmDateTime.Style style = this._style;
    DateTime userTime = this._userTime;
    if (SerializationState.IsInPlatformContext)
    {
        switch (style)
        {
            case CrmDateTime.Style.User:
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("CrmDateTime on the server must provide date-time in universal time zone. Current value passed contains time in the user time zone only.");
            }
            case CrmDateTime.Style.Universal:
            {
                userTime = SerializationState.ConvertUtcTimeToUserTime(this._universalTime);
                userTime = CrmDateTime.AdjustToLimits(userTime);
                style = CrmDateTime.Style.Both;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    switch (style)
    {
        case CrmDateTime.Style.User:
        {
            CultureInfo invariantCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            object[] objArray = new object[] { userTime };
            return string.Format(invariantCulture, "{0:s}", objArray);
        }
        case CrmDateTime.Style.Universal:
        {
            CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            object[] objArray1 = new object[] { this._universalTime };
            return string.Format(cultureInfo, "{0:s}Z", objArray1);
        }
        case CrmDateTime.Style.Both:
        {
            TimeSpan timeSpan = userTime - this._universalTime;
            CrmException.Assert((timeSpan.TotalDays < -1 ? false : timeSpan.TotalDays <= 1), "User and universal time should not be further than 1 day away.");
            if (timeSpan.Hours <= 0)
            {
                CultureInfo invariantCulture1 = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                object[] hours = new object[] { userTime, -timeSpan.Hours, -timeSpan.Minutes };
                str = string.Format(invariantCulture1, "{0:s}-{1:00}:{2:00}", hours);
            }
            else
            {
                CultureInfo cultureInfo1 = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                object[] hours1 = new object[] { userTime, timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes };
                str = string.Format(cultureInfo1, "{0:s}+{1:00}:{2:00}", hours1);
            }
            return str;
        }
    }
    CultureInfo invariantCulture2 = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    object[] str1 = new object[] { style.ToString() };
    throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(invariantCulture2, "Invalid CrmDateTime style: {0}", str1));
}
```